# The Matrix of a Symmetry of $\mathbb{R^2}$ onto the axis $L(u)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $$ u=\left( {\begin{array}{c}
>    a\\
> b
>   \end{array} } \right)
> \hspace{3ex}  ||u||=1   \hspace{3ex}
> $$
>   Prove ***A*** is the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R^2}$ onto the axis $L(u)$
>   $$
>  A=uu^t=
>   \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    a^2 & ab \\
>    ab & b^2 \\
>   \end{array} } \right
> ]$$
>
> Then prove ***S*** is the matrix of the symmetry of $\mathbb{R^2}$ onto the axis $L(u)$
>
> $$S=2A-I$$

**My work :**

Let $v=(x\ y \ z)^t$, we know $p_L(v)=u\frac{<u,v>}{||u||}=u<u,v>=uu^tv=Av\Rightarrow $ A is the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R^2}$ onto the axis $L(u)$

How can I prove $S=2A-I$?

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

The reflection of any vector $v$ across $L(u)$ can be computed as $2\operatorname{proj}_u(v)-v$, which can be rewritten (using the first part of the question) as $2Av-v=(2A-I)v=Sv$.

$S$ describes a Householder transformation, common in numerical linear algebra.